# Could not proceed due to error in ExpanableListAdapter

Tags: java, android, expandablelistadapter

I'm trying this code and found this error:

[image]

I don't know the reason.

If anyone knows it kindly help me.

Comment: what is the type of listDataHeader and listDataChild in you code ?

Comment: @AdnanMaqbool type is String

Comment: @Mahwish what are params of your SimpleExpanadableListAdapter constructor ?

Comment: public  ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

Comment: @AdnanMaqbool Thanks a lot, it resolved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor has 4 params and your are passing only three while calling